# Pushing to bitbucket: authorization failed

Tags: mercurial, push, bitbucket

I'm a *git & github* user that's new to *mercurial & bitbucket* and I'm trying to use bitbucket for a project.

So far I've got write access to a new *private* bitbucket repository, and [I got started](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Getting+Started+with+Bitbucket) by:

1. cloning
2. adding my existing project
3. committing
4. trying push, I get `authorization failed` via:

#### HTTPS

```
$ hg push https://mariusbutuc@bitbucket.org/DB2UAdmin/repo
http authorization required
realm: Bitbucket.org HTTP
user: mariusbutuc
password: 
pushing to https://mariusbutuc@bitbucket.org/DB2UAdmin/repo
searching for changes
abort: authorization failed
```

#### SSH

```
$ hg push ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/DB2UAdmin/repo
pushing to ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/DB2UAdmin/repo
searching for changes
remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: added 1 changesets with 9664 changes to 9664 files
remote: You're not allowed to write to this repository.
remote: transaction abort!
remote: rollback completed
remote: abort: pretxnchangegroup.bb_perm hook failed
```

also attempted via simple **HTTP**, got similar results as with **HTTPS**.

How can I get it to work?

*Extra details:*

- python 2.7.1+
- mercurial 1.7.5
- on Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The bitbucket account was opened under my gmail address [*addr A*].
2. The SSH key was made using the address from my company [*addr B*].
3. *addr B* was added to my account as a secondary address.
4. I had writing access for the mariusbutuc account, that had both addresses.

*...I still couldn't pass the auth test.*

1. Got an invitation form the Admin, on my work address - *addr B*. With admin rights, not only write.
2. Trying to accept the invitation, I couldn't: my account already had access to the repository.
   Had to revoke my own access, just to be able to
3. accept the admin rights.
4. Pushed successfully via **SSH**:

```
$ hg push ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/DB2UAdmin/repo
pushing to ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/DB2UAdmin/repo
searching for changes
remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: added 1 changesets with 9664 changes to 9664 files
remote: bb/acl: mariusbutuc is allowed. accepted payload.
```

I still have no idea why pushing via **HTTPS** [*username/password*] failed!

Answer (score 1):

For those of you that arrive here from googling "pretxnchangegroup.bb_perm hook failed" this can be caused by trying to merge to a branch that you do not have the "write" permission under "branch permissions" on bitbucket.
Presumably this is because you should have used a pull request for the merge rather than going ahead and merging on your local.